# Stop continuous scroll smoothdivScroll

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm using Thomas Kahn's smoothdivscroll and want to know how can you STOP continuous scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check his docs [here](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/publicMethods.html)

search for `stopAutoScrolling` or `disable`
i tried disable [here](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/demo.html) using chrome console and it worked

```
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("disable");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#makeMeScrollable" ).bind( "mouseover", function () { 
$( this ).smoothDivScroll( "stopAutoScrolling" );
} ).bind( "mouseout", function () {  
$( this ).smoothDivScroll( "startAutoScrolling" );
} );
```